# Xamarin.Forms.Maps How i can rotation pins like a taxi

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm working with (iOS) [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/).
Is it possible to rotate a pin (marker) on the map in its direction, like on taxi maps?

[Example a gif](https://overcoder.net/img/1/12/38/113764.gif)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaVuh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/ It supports the Pin rotation.

Set yoru custom pin with Pin.Icon property first.

The code below used the silder to make the custom pin marker do the 360 rotation.

```
sliderRotation.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _pinTokyo.Rotation = (float)e.NewValue;

            if (_pinTokyo.Rotation>= 0 && _pinTokyo.Rotation <= 60)
            {
                _pinTokyo.InfoWindowAnchor = new Point(0.5, 0.0);
            }

            if (_pinTokyo.Rotation > 60 && _pinTokyo.Rotation <= 120)
            {
                _pinTokyo.InfoWindowAnchor = new Point(0.0, 0.5);
            }

            if (_pinTokyo.Rotation > 120 && _pinTokyo.Rotation <= 210)
            {
                _pinTokyo.InfoWindowAnchor = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
            }

            if (_pinTokyo.Rotation > 210 && _pinTokyo.Rotation < 270)
            {
                _pinTokyo.InfoWindowAnchor = new Point(1.0, 0.25);
            }

            if (_pinTokyo.Rotation > 270 && _pinTokyo.Rotation < 360)
            {
                _pinTokyo.InfoWindowAnchor = new Point(0.5, 0.0);
            }
        };
```

Please do not forget to get the API key. You could download the sample code from the GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps